# kdb/q Creating new columns based on the beginning of a grouping of rows

Tags: grouping, kdb

The table below has some information about running races. There are multiple rows that are attributed to the same race, and you can tell by looking at the FirstID and SecondID columns. The SourceID column connects the multiple rows together.

For example, row 2 is a continuation of row 1 because the SecondID of row 1 is the FirstID of row 2. An easy way to see this is by grouping by SourceID, which keeps the first FirstID value of the chain.

| FirstID | SecondID | SourceID | Race | Style | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123ABC | 456DEF | 123ABC | Atlantic | Timed |  |
| 456DEF | 789GHI | 123ABC | SubAtlantic |  |  |
| 349UYH | 286IWD | 349UYH | Pacific | Untimed |  |
| 286IWD | 585YYY | 349UYH | SubPacific |  |  |

```
input:([] FirstID:`123ABC`456DEF`349UYH`286IWD; SecondID:`456DEF`789GHI`286IWD`585YYY; SourceID: `123ABC`123ABC`349UYH`349UYH; Race: `Atlantic`SubAtlantic`Pacific`SubPacific; Style: `Timed``Untimed`)
```

I want to add a few more columns based on this information, namely ParentRace and IsTimed, so that the output looks like this:

| FirstID | SecondID | SourceID | Race | Style | ParentRace | IsTimed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123ABC | 456DEF | 123ABC | Atlantic | Timed | Atlantic | Yes |
| 456DEF | 789GHI | 123ABC | SubAtlantic |  | Atlantic | Yes |
| 349UYH | 286IWD | 349UYH | Pacific | Untimed | Pacific | No |
| 286IWD | 585YYY | 349UYH | SubPacific |  | Pacific | No |

ParentRace is the value of the Race at the beginning of the chain (i.e. first row that begins a chain) and is applied to the rest of the chain, grouped by SourceID

IsTimed shows whether or not the beginning of the chain is `Timed and applies to the rest of the chain, grouped by SourceID

Does anyone know how to add these two columns based on the initial row of the chain? Let me know if you need me to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
update ParentRace:first Race, isTimed:`No`Yes @ `Timed=first Style by SourceID from input
```

Comment: Quick question, how would you handle a symbol with spaces? For ex., Instead of Untimed if it said Not Timed, I tried replacing with `$"Not Timed" but get a type error

Comment: I expect you're missing brackets (which would result in trying to cast a boolean to a symbol). This works:
`update ParentRace:first Race, isTimed:\`Yes\`No @ (\`$"Not Timed")=first Style by SourceID from input`
You could also use `like` : 
`update ParentRace:first Race, isTimed:\`Yes\`No @ string[first Style] like "Not Timed" by SourceID from input`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that could work is to do dictionary lookups:

```
q)update ParentRace:(FirstID!Race)SourceID,isTimed:`Timed=(FirstID!Style)SourceID from input
FirstID SecondID SourceID Race        Style   ParentRace isTimed
----------------------------------------------------------------
123ABC  456DEF   123ABC   Atlantic    Timed   Atlantic   1
456DEF  789GHI   123ABC   SubAtlantic         Atlantic   1
349UYH  286IWD   349UYH   Pacific     Untimed Pacific    0
286IWD  585YYY   349UYH   SubPacific          Pacific    0
```

This assumes your FirstID values are unique